# Notify user if wrong data type entered (Python 3)

Tags: string, python-3.x, types, int

How do I change this code so that the program can notify the user that he/she has entered a text instead of a number?

```
Enter_a_Number = int(input("Enter a Number: "))
if Enter_a_Number == str:
    print("Only Numbers Allowed")
```

Comment: and do what after? Do you want to keep asking for input until the user gives a valid response?

Answer (score 0):

You need to explore the basics of error-handling.

See [Python.org Tutorial - Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

```
while (True):
    try:
        Enter_a_Number = int(input("Enter a Number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid number")

print(Enter_a_Number)
```

In this specific case, the int() function will 'throw' a ValueError if it can not convert the string to an integer.  You can decide what to do when that happens.

Comment: Thanks. This really helped me.